# Is "shared on demand of a friend" a good title?

Tags: sentence-construction

A friend of mine asked me to share a clip. I did so and wrote **Shared on demand of a friend** above it. Is it OK? What are the best ways to put this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shared on **demand** of a friend.

seems a bit harsh, like you were forced to do it. Better would be:

> Shared on **request** of a friend.

If you check the definitions I think you can see the difference.